# Create a class library in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

This it's probably going to be a question with a very easy answer... But I've been googling for a while and I didn't find any.

I'm working on a project that requires some classes to be used in more NetBeans projects (and EJB deployed on Glassfish and a client to call it). 
Now, to make it work, I just imported the whole EJB project into the client project as a library, but everytime I launch the client, Netbeans redeploys the whole client and that takes a lot of time.

That's why I'd like to extract just those few interfaces I need from the server project, package them in a .jar and link that to the client.

In Eclipse it was easy enough (right click on your classes, export as jar). Here I can't really find anything of the sort. The only export option I see is used to export the whole project as a .zip.

(Copy pasting the .java files in the client project would also work but a .jar would be cleaner I think)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the problem.
I use shared classes a lot, and package them into their own project.

Possible process:

1. Create new project, "Java class library".
2. Move the required classes to that project.
3. In your main project, open Properties, Libraries and "Add Project" to link to your library project.

Comment: How do I make it work with dependencies like javax.persistence? I tried to move some entities classes into a library project, and those imports weren't working (do I have to add Glassfish as a dependency?)

Comment: I tried to add the "JavaEE API library" and "JavaEE from Glassfish" to the library project and then move the entities. The import were resolved. I them imported the jar in both my EJB and my client application. Deployed the EJB, and ran the application, I get "ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class Entities.Person, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation" when I call a method of the EJB.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I needed to specify each entity I wanted to use in the persistence.xml manually, the default option to use all the listed classes did not work, neither did using <jar-file> and pointing it directly to the library's jar.